# What is the preferred angular way of fetching and updating table data from a (non-reactive) API source?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I've been digging into Angular and Im trying to wrap my head around rxjs while learning basic Angular. I'm trying to set a good precedent for structure and how to dynamically update templates and component data, but I don't know what the preferred method for doing this is.
I have an API that on GET returns all `Customers`s, so I made a specific service for this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomerApiService {
  api_url: string;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private snack: SnackService,
    @Inject('base_api_url') private baseAPIURL: string
  ) {
    this.api_url = baseAPIURL + 'customers';
  }

  getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.api_url).pipe(
      tap((_) => this.snack.log('Fetched customers')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Customer[]>(`'Get Customers'`))
    );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      this.snack.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

I'm using this service in a component that displays a table:

```
export class CustomerList {
customers: Customer[];

constructor(private customer_api: CustomerApiService) {
  this.customers =[];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.cust_api.getCustomers().subscribe(..);
}
```

And it works, but if Im POSTing or PUTing, the API will respond with the object/data that was inserted. In my head, I should use BehaviorSubject or some other method for this to automatically add that returned Customer to the table/list of customers once I implement `postCustomer` or similarly. What is the best way of going about this? I've read about the  `| async` pipe which people rave about but I'm uncertain whether I should do this or manually append to my list or what? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use ```NgRx``` with ```side effects```

Comment: same idea, instead of get, you do the post, and the api also returns a value for you, just like you do with get

Comment: @Jimmy so I don't bother with Behaviorsubjects etc? I just keep a list of `customers` in the component that is "manually" refreshed on post?

Comment: No, I mean you start as normal (as you did with "get"). And then you read and learn more about other techniques, then apply it, compares different techniques together. Instead of people tell you what to do, you try it yourself first then ask what still unclear to you.